# Square Root Subtraction Question

Tags: radicals

Is there any way I can simplify the equation $ \sqrt{a-b}-\sqrt{a}$  ?

I understand that there is no way to simplify $ \sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} $

Comment: If you could simply $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{a-b}$, you could simplify $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{c}$ by setting $b=a-c$.

Comment: Generally, no.  $\sqrt{a-b}-\sqrt{a}$ is as simplified as it will be.  There do exist some special cases of course for specific values.

Comment: When $|b| < |a|$, it is sometimes helpful to write it
$$\sqrt{a-b} - \sqrt{a}=\sqrt{a}\left(\sqrt{1-\tfrac{b}{a}} - 1\right).$$
You can then apply the binomial theorem.